# Python Pandas and excel xlsx cell formats

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

So what I need to do is to get xlsx file to pandas dataframe then do some things with it and save it back as xlsx file.

How I do it is:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import datetime

path = r'D:\Test\Test.xlsx'
path2 = r'D:\Test\TestResult.xlsx'

dataFrame = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=0, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])
print(dataFrame.dtypes)

dataFrame.Hours = pd.to_datetime(dataFrame.Hours, format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
print(dataFrame.dtypes)

book = load_workbook(path)
firstSheetName = book.sheetnames[0]
ws = book.get_sheet_by_name(firstSheetName)
book.remove(ws)
book.create_sheet(firstSheetName, 0)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path2, engine='openpyxl', date_format='yyyy-mm-dd')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
dataFrame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=firstSheetName, index=False)

writer.save()
```

So far everything works fine, file get saved etc.
But problem I do have is that in base file Test.xlsx my "Hours" column is of custom type (hh:mm:ss), and when I import it to dataframe it is recognized as "object" type.
Also when I do save that data back into excel testResult.xlsx, this column changes to "general".

I was trying to change "object" type in dataframe to "datetime" type using code below but it has no effect, Hours is still visible as "object":

```
dataFrame.Hours = pd.to_datetime(dataFrame.Hours, format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
```

So what I need helped with is, how to save that dataframe back to excel xlsx file where "Hours" column is set as custom "hh:mm:ss" ???

Excel file is Test.xlsx and that how it looks inside:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uu7g7xmMKy51BHpy0Up3T47VTHwtH9U_9PdlBSlaK80/edit?usp=sharing

"Hours" column is of custom type "hh:mm:ss"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of both the `date_format` and `datetime_format` parameters from the [**`.ExcelWriter()`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas-excelwriter)

Just format the columns accordingly. In your case `FromDate` and `ToDate` to the `datetime.date` objects, and `Hours` to `datetime.datetime` objects.

```
df['FromDate'] = df['FromDate'].dt.date
df['ToDate'] = df['ToDate'].dt.date
df['Hours'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hours'], format='%H:%M:%S')
```

And then specify the output format:

```
pd.ExcelWriter(path2, engine='openpyxl', date_format='yyyy-mm-dd', datetime_format='hh:mm:ss')
```

Comment: it does change the format indeed but result in excel file is still wrong. Before it was showing only hours in that custom format. Now it shows date when You click on the cell to edit it 1900-01-01 23:59:50. I need to have my result without that date.

Answer (score 1):

Delete `.dt.time`, it can be converted to `datetime64`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after hours of trying I have found a solution. Big thanks goes to @afonso for helping me convert that string to datatime type.

Problem I still had was due to the fact that after conversion python was setting date as "1900-01-01 23:59:50" and excel was reading it as 1.324324243 (date and time format) instead of 0.1234325 (only time format - as date it looks like "1900-0-0 23:59:50").

So what I did was to use excel "bug" of not being able to read dates below year 1900 and substracted one day from my python datetime using this code:

```
dataFrame['Hours'] = dataFrame['Hours'] + pd.Timedelta(days=-1)
```

This resulted in sending to excel date "1899-12-31 23:59:50", and since excel couldnt read that date as date it autoamticaly changed it to "1900-01-00 23:59:50" and this solved my problem because that was exactly format I had on my input from excel.

Big thanks to everyone for help.